# Where is the visual studio 2010 setup and deployment project template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment, project-template

In VS 2008, when I create a project I can add a setup project easily.  File->Add->New Project... then in Project types: select Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment - and there are a whole load of installed templates - including Setup Project to create an MSI installer.

But in VS 2010 - there are no templates in the Setup and Deployment - I'm using the Pro edition, not Express or beta:  Is this the same for you - or do I have a duff installation of VS 2010?  Otherwise how do I create an MSI installer for my projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pro, they are under Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment -> Visual Studio Installer

The 5 listed ones are:
Setup Project
Web Setup Project
Merge Module Project
Setup Wizard
CAB Project

Comment: Thanks for the info: I didn't spot the sub directory of Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 2):

I see them in the usual place on Premium. There's now an additional one for InstallShield Limited Edition. According to the links below they should be available on Professional:

- [Visual Studio Installer
  Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)
- [Choosing a Windows
  Installer Deployment Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500.aspx)